# Open WPF Application from Excel VSTO project

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have VSTO Excel tool written in C# and I use WPF form to display some data. WPF form is in a different project, but in the same solution with Excel VSTO project. If I open the WPF form in the same thread with Excel, it somehow damage Excel and it starts doing some strange things. But if I run WPF form in a different thread, everything works perfectly. So the code below should be  OK:

```
if (app != null)
{
// When click the button again and WPF form is opened already, bring it on top.
    BringDatabaseToFront();
}
else
{
    t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        app = new App(_synchronizationContext, currentCaller);

        App.ResourceAssembly = app.GetType().Assembly;

        app.InitializeComponent();

        app.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

        /* Makes the thread support message pumping
        * Dispecher is the Context of the WPF DB form  */
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    // WPF MUST be on a single-threaded apartment
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

The problem starts when I shut-down the tool (Excel). It freezes and stays frozen forever. I have tried many different way to shut-down WPF form, but the only one that works and closes everything is:

```
public void ShutDownAttempt()
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

That works, but now I have another problem. If the users have several other Excel workbooks opened, this code closes all of them without any warning, even they have data that is not saved. So this is dangerous.

It looks like it’s not that easy to shut down WPF application if it is running on another thread from the main application. Does anyone have experience with using WPF form from Excel?

Comment: I have similar task and it's going pretty OK without using any threading for displaying WPF forms. What exactly are you doing with the WPF in your VSTO app?

Comment: I have a relatively large database (40,000+ records), so I use WPF form for data filtering and selection and then I send the selected data to Excel VSTO for curve fitting and analysis. I have several projects in the solution: Excel VSTO, WPF database form, Entity Framework Data Model, and a Helper module which I use to make the communication between the objects in different threads.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call the `Shutdown()` method of the `App` using its dispatcher:

```
app.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> { app.Shutdown(); });
```

Comment: I’ve tried a couple similar ways to shutdown WPF module:   


`app.MainWindow.Closed += (s2, e2) => app.MainWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();`  


`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => app.Shutdown()))`  


Neither one is working. Probably because this module is pretty large and in addition have Entity Framework module. Probably I have to try with an empty WPF form just to check the concepts.